# Python Subprocess.Popen stdout and stderr problems

Tags: python, process, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I have created a script (x) that can start and stop some other scripts (y). The "y" scripts redirect `sys.stdout = SomeClass()` and `sys.stderr = SomeClass()`.
`SomeClass()` simply sends a pyside6 signal with the stdout/stderr written text and places that into a text area. The problem is, however, that the starter script (x), outputs EVERYTHING into the console that pops up when I start the "y" script (i.e. the redirect part in the "y" script doesn't work).
To clarify, I want stdout to ONLY go to the text area, and stderr to ONLY go to the console.
What could be causing this? I suppose it could be something with subprocess.Popen redirecting stdout and stderr to the console that is opened when I run the command that starts the "y" scripts.

I have tried adding: `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the "x" script as an argument in subprocess.Popen and I've also tried `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` to the "x" script as an argument in subprocess.Popen, but this removes the output completely.

The class that I redirect it to is located inside the "y" script (the script that gets started by the "x" script using Popen.) and is called SomeClass(). It looks like this:

```
class SomeClass(QObject):
    textWritten = Signal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.textWritten.emit(str(text))

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

And this is the code where I redirect the signal and stdout (Also located inside the "y" script):

```
sys.stdout = SomeClass()
sys.stderr = SomeClass()
sys.stdout.textWritten.connect(self.handle_text_changed)
sys.stderr.textWritten.connect(self.handle_text_changed)
```

And the `handle_text_changed`function looks like this:

```
def handle_text_changed(self, text):
    self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
    self.textEdit.insertPlainText(text)
    self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
```

The part of the "x" script where I start the "y" script looks like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["deactivate.bat", "&&", "cd", path, "&&", "SET", "PYTHONPATH=pathtothescript".format(path), "&&", r".\venv\Scripts\python", "main.py"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
proc.poll()
```

Comment: can you create a [mre] ?

Comment: Do you mean that the output goes to console and text area or console only?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Both stdout and stderr goes to the console, when I want stdout to only go to the text area, and stderr to only go to the console.

Comment: Why did you wrote then that you redirect with `sys.stderr = SomeClass()`? You should also at least show the relevant code of "SomeClass" which handles redirection, a minimal reproducible example would be better.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've edited my question to include the functions that handle the redirection (all of them are located inside the "y" script, which is the script started by the "x" script). The part where I do `sys.stderr = SomeClass()` doesn't affect whether or not it gets redirected to the console since it's located inside the "y" script, and I redirect that to the text area.